# How to display data in mat-option angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a object and i want to display it in the form fields, all fields are filled after click button instead of select option. what is going wrong.

Please help me to find the error. Below is my code.

**Object**

```
{
   id: 12
   category_name: "category 1"
   author_id: 5
   customer_id: 12
}
```

**Typescript**

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
   id: [null],
   category_name: [null, Validators.required],
   author_id: [this.auth.loggedInUserId.id],
   customer_id: [null]
})

editCategory(data) {
  this.form.patchValue(data);
  console.log(this.form.value);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Select Customer</mat-label>
   <mat-select [formControl]="form.controls.customer_id">
      <mat-option></mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" value="{{customer.id}}">{{customer.firstname}}
         {{customer.lastname}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: what's the data in `customers`?

Comment: @Mridul customers contain same data as i mention in object

Comment: I Just want to fill my field on getting the object

Comment: I hope customers contains array object?

Comment: Yes, you r right, but i just show a sample of that

Comment: Also, it should be `[value] = "customer.id"`

Comment: @Mridul it works, you save my day...

Comment: Okay cool good to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. I hope this will work fine.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.id"> 
    {{customer.firstname}{{customer.lastname}}
 </mat-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Typescript**

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
   id: new FormControl(0),
   category_name: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
   author_id: new FormControl(this.auth.loggedInUserId.id),
   customer_id: new FormControl(0)
})
```

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select Customer" formControlName="customer_id" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.id">{{customer.firstname}} {{customer.lastname}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```